# Unable to create a spring starter project in STS

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to create a spring starter project in STS. I am selecting the gradle distribution and the Spring web dependency. When I click on finish I am getting the following error message. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASwWo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to configure your proxy in your IDE.
Please look at this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connection issue from your end caused due probably due to unstable network. In any case you can always add dependencies and download the project from https://start.spring.io